# How should HTTP PATCH communicate the removal of resource attributes when using a FieldMask

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto, http-patch, grpc-python

**TL,DR**; *How should HTTP PATCH communicate the removal of resource attributes when using a [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#fieldmask)?*

Google's [API Design Guide](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/) for implementing [standard methods](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods) states that a partial [update](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_methods#update) should be achieved using a [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#fieldmask). Below is my own contrived example to update a `Test` resource:

The API of the service defines a `Test` resource and an [HTTP PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) method (`UpdateTest`) for partial updates.

```proto
// A test resource.
message Test {
  string name = 1;
  google.protobuf.StringValue description = 2;
}

// Request message for update method.
message UpdateTestRequest {
  // The resource name of the test to be updated. 
  string name = 1;
  // Wrap the actual data in a data field.
  Test test = 2;
  // Field mask to support partial updates.
  google.protobuf.FieldMask update_mask = 3;
}

// Partially update a Test resource.
rpc UpdateTest(UpdateTestRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
     patch: "v1/{name=tests/*}"
     body: "*"
   };
}
```

An equally contrived server implementation uses the [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#fieldmask) to merge the resources (proto messages):

```py
updated_test = v1_test_pb2.Test(name = 'Updated')
original_test = v1_test_pb2.Test(
  name = 'Original',
  description = google.protobuf.wrappers_pb2.StringValue(
    value = 'I am Original!')
)

mask = google.protobuf.field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(
  paths = ['name', 'description']
)

# from, to
mask.MergeMessage(updated_test, original_test)
print(updated_test)
```

The end result is a patch `Test` resource:

```
name: "Updated"
description {
  value: "I am Original!"
}
```

Clearing the `description` field removes the property altogether:

```py
updated_test = v1_test_pb2.Test(name = 'Updated')
updated_test.ClearField('description')

original_test = v1_test_pb2.Test(
  name = 'Original',
  description = google.protobuf.wrappers_pb2.StringValue(
    value = 'I am Original!')
)

# from, to
mask.MergeMessage(updated_test, original_test)
print(updated_test)
```

...the final patched `Test` resource would be:

```
name: "Updated"
```

Great. But how would this be encoded in the HTTP PATCH request?

The only "solution" I can think of is that, if the [FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#fieldmask) contains `description` but the updated `Test` resource doesn't provide a value, it should be removed using [ClearField](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#singular-fields-proto3).

This would require manually visiting each field either in the mask, or the `Test` messaage (**or both**) to determine whether the it should be removed. This seems *crazy*, especially if a resource has many fields.